# Ionic rendering inside ion-content when using window.open

Tags: ionic-framework

I am having what I think may be a syntax problem when I try to use an onclick event. I have a page that renders the following correctly:

```
 <ion-view>
    <ion-content>
       <a href="geo:{{latitude}},{{longitude}}?z=11">
                View Map
       </a>
    </ion-content>
 </ion-view>
```

Now what I am trying to do here is to change the above with this:

```
 <ion-view>
    <ion-content>
            <a onclick="window.open('geo:{{latitude}},{{longitude}}?z=11&q={{latitude}},{{longitude}}(Treasure)', '_system', 'location=yes');" href="geo:{{latitude}},{{longitude}}?z=11&q={{latitude}},{{longitude}}(Treasure)">View Map</a>
    </ion-content>
 </ion-view>
```

The problem is that the variables inside window.open (e.g. {{latitude}}, etc...) are not rendered and I still see the {{latitude}} etc.. instead of the real values.

I know as a fact that the link is correct. If I hard code the values as the sample below, the link works just fine and I can be able to open an external Google Maps call from my app:

```
 <ion-view>
    <ion-content>
            <a onclick="window.open('geo:0,0?z=11&q=0,0(Treasure)', '_system', 'location=yes');" href="geo:0,0?z=11&q=0,0(Treasure)">View Map</a>
    </ion-content>
 </ion-view>
```

I use 0,0 here only as a sample, on my app I use real coordinates.
Any ideas would be gladly appreciate it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question, please see the following post, 
http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-rendering-inside-ion-content-when-using-window-open/16435/2

Lesson learned here, whenever you are dealing with external links in your app, please make sure you look at the value you are passing to the link if it is dynamically generated. In this case, I didn't see an unsafe prefix added to my links.

I hope this helps someone else with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a better solution for this issue:

```
    <a class="button button-assertive" 
   ng-href="http:// url .com/{{id}}/discount"
   onclick='window.open(this.href, "_system", "location=yes"); return false;'>
    </a>
```

Details here: http://technotip.com/4578/ionic-app-open-external-links-in-mobile-browser/